# How to deal with bool valued needed operation like tf.nn.fused_batch_norm in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

For functions like `tf.layers.batch_normalization`, it is easy to use a placeholder `train_flag` as input for the `training` argument, and after we define the whole network, we can feed in `True` or `False` for `train_flag` under training or inference phases.

However, for operations like `tf.nn.fused_batch_norm` (defined in [nn_impl.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py)), which only accepts python bool as input for argument `is_training`, does it mean that we will need to construct the network twice under training and inference phases with difference `is_training` arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition file of [`tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization.py),

```
def _fused_batch_norm(self, inputs, training):
    """Returns the output of fused batch norm."""

    def _fused_batch_norm_training():
        return nn.fused_batch_norm(
            inputs,
            self.gamma,
            self.beta,
            epsilon=self.epsilon)

    def _fused_batch_norm_inference():
        return nn.fused_batch_norm(
            inputs,
            self.gamma,
            self.beta,
            mean=self.moving_mean,
            variance=self.moving_variance,
            epsilon=self.epsilon,
            is_training=False)

    output, mean, variance = tf_utils.smart_cond(
        training, _fused_batch_norm_training, _fused_batch_norm_inference)
    if not self._bessels_correction_test_only:
        # Remove Bessel's correction to be consistent with non-fused batch norm.
        # Note that the variance computed by fused batch norm is
        # with Bessel's correction.
        sample_size = math_ops.cast(
                array_ops.size(inputs) / array_ops.size(variance), variance.dtype)
        factor = (sample_size - math_ops.cast(1.0, variance.dtype)) / sample_size
        variance *= factor

    training_value = tf_utils.constant_value(training)
    if training_value is None:
        momentum = tf_utils.smart_cond(training,
                                       lambda: self.momentum,
                                       lambda: 1.0)
    else:
        momentum = ops.convert_to_tensor(self.momentum)
    if training_value or training_value is None:
        mean_update = self._assign_moving_average(self.moving_mean, mean,
                                                  momentum)
        variance_update = self._assign_moving_average(self.moving_variance,
                                                      variance, momentum)
        self.add_update(mean_update, inputs=True)
        self.add_update(variance_update, inputs=True)

    return output
```

It utilizes `training_value = tf_utils.constant_value(training)` and then uses `if training_value is None`, where `tf_utils.constant_value` should be `tf.contrib.util.constant_value`